# how does app.single work in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework and also to angularjs. I am trying to understand how does list items get mapped to app.single. In other example I found use of "list.item" for parent "list" state, but that didnt work for me ([egghead.io tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router)).
I am using basic ionic app with sidemenu.
Can someone please explain how is app.single getting mapped to playlist item?

> playlists.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlists">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
    {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

> playlist.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlist">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Playlist</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

> controller.js

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.playlists = [
{ title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
{ title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
{ title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
{ title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
{ title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
{ title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
];
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
});
```

> app.js

```
.state('app.playlists', {
  url: "/playlists",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/playlists.html",
      controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.single', {
  url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
       templateUrl: "templates/playlist.html",
       controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on my answer, @vikramaditya234?

Comment: The boilerplate ionic code which comes with the `sidemenu` blueprint has two controllers with _almost_ identical variable names: "_Playlist**s**Ctrl_" and "_PlaylistCtrl_" — this could be pretty confusing at first sight. Imo, it would have been much clearer to have a **PlaylistController** and a **PlaylistItemController**. In fact, this would be even better: **ItemListController** and **ItemDetailController**. Bad naming can really kill you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your playlists.html, there's a html tag which gives url to target template for each playlist items.

```
href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}"
```

So, once a user taps on an item in current list, he will get redirected to "/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}" page.

And then, please kindly focus on app.js which links each controller to desired url.

```
url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
```

This is the part where your 'app.single' state is linked to each playlist item. In this case '/app' is omitted by abstract param of 'app' state definition.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i understand the concept. I was confused with state name and URL.